# How do I copy/cut text which I selected using shift+Arrow keys in Nano?

Tags: linux, nano

When I am trying to copy/cut in Nano command while using Shift and Arrow key to select the lines, its not working. But if I am selecting the lines with my mouse to copy/cut, its working.

Is it normal or I have to change any setting.

Answer (score 0):

- `Alt-A` starts marking. Move the cursor to mark the text.
- `Alt-6` is copy
- Move to the target location.
- `Ctrl-U` is paste

The shortcuts are displayed at the bottom of the screen. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it but its still not working. If I am selecting text with mouse and use Alt-6, its working. But if I am selecting text with Alt-A , its still not coping the text in "nano" . Rest everywhere its working fine. But not in nano.

Comment: I don't know any other method, sorry. In my console it works. Can you try instead of `Alt-A` to use `Ctrl-6`? This also worked for me.

Comment: Nope. It didnt work. Thanks you so much for taking your time out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Shift+Arrow Key to select text. Ctrl+K to cut or Alt+6 to copy. Ctrl+U to paste in either case.

If you select with the mouse, these shortcuts will not work. In that case, you have to use Ctrl+Shift+C to cupy and Ctrl+Shift+V to paste.

Nano has it's own internal cursor, which is what you're using when you Shift+Arrow to select text. Notice that if you select some text with Shift+Arrow, and then select different text with the mouse, it does not deselect the originally selected area.

[image: Demonstrating first select with Shift+Arrow, and then with mouse, followed by Ctrl+K to cut and then Ctrl+U to copy several times.]